# Example of handling chained errors in Go with help of CustomError object

Tags: go

My code snippet represents a way of handling chained errors. I need a code-review to understand whether my way is idiomatic and relevant for the 2021?

My personal requirements:

1. I want each package of my project to have an `errors.go` file with defined sentinel-style  errors. This, in my opinion, hugely improves readability/maintainability.
2. I want to utilize new `errors.Is/As` functionality.
3. I want to hide implementation details of underlying packages. In my code snippet - I don't want the `web` package to know anything about `repository.NotFoundError` and `repository.DatabaseError`. But I do want my top-level web error to have full chain of underlying error strings (possibly, error contexts) for describing them in logs, HTTP responses, etc.

Here is my humble snippet (one may launch it with go test):

````golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

// the code below should be kept in some kind of common place 

type CustomError struct {
    Message string
    Child   error
}

func (cerr *CustomError) Error() string {
    if cerr.Child != nil {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", cerr.Message, cerr.Child.Error())
    }
    return cerr.Message
}

func (cerr *CustomError) Unwrap() error {
    return cerr.Child
}

func (cerr *CustomError) Wrap(child error) error {
    cerr.Child = child
    return cerr
}

func CustomErrorBuilder(message string, child error) *CustomError {
    return &CustomError{Message: message, Child: child}
}


// the code below represents the 'repository' package


var (
    NotFoundError = CustomErrorBuilder("NotFoundError", nil)
    DatabaseError = CustomErrorBuilder("DatabaseError", nil)
)

func QueryUser(id int) (string, error) {
    if id == 0 {
        return "User 0", nil
    }
    if id == 1 {
        return "User 1", nil
    }
    if id == 100 {
        return "", DatabaseError
    }

    return "", NotFoundError
}

// the code below represents the 'core' package

var (
    InfrastructureError = CustomErrorBuilder("InfrastructureError", nil)
    BusinessLogicError  = CustomErrorBuilder("BusinessLogicError", nil)
)

func UserHasName(id int, name string) (bool, error) {
    userName, err := QueryUser(id)
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, NotFoundError) {
            return false, BusinessLogicError.Wrap(NotFoundError)
        }
        if errors.Is(err, DatabaseError) {
            return false, InfrastructureError.Wrap(DatabaseError)
        }
    }

    if userName == name {
        return true, nil
    } else {
        return false, nil
    }
}

// the code below represents the 'web' package

func Handler(id int, name string) (int, string) {
    result, err := UserHasName(id, name)
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, BusinessLogicError) {
            return 404, fmt.Sprintf("NOT FOUND %v", err)
        }
        if errors.Is(err, InfrastructureError) {
            return 500, fmt.Sprintf("INTERNAL SERVER ERROR %v", err)
        }
    }
    return 200, fmt.Sprintf("OK %t", result)
}

// This test checks errors wrapping

func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        userId         int
        userName       string
        expectedStatus int
        expectedBody   string
    }{
        {userId: 0, userName: "User 0", expectedStatus: 200, expectedBody: "OK true"},
        {userId: 1, userName: "User 0", expectedStatus: 200, expectedBody: "OK false"},
        {userId: 2, userName: "", expectedStatus: 404, expectedBody: "NOT FOUND BusinessLogicError: NotFoundError"},
        {userId: 100, userName: "", expectedStatus: 500, expectedBody: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR InfrastructureError: DatabaseError"},
    }

    for i, tcase := range testCases {
        t.Run(fmt.Sprintf("Case %v", i), func(t *testing.T) {
            status, body := Handler(tcase.userId, tcase.userName)
            if status != tcase.expectedStatus {
                t.Fatalf("%v != %v", status, tcase.expectedStatus)
            }
            if body != tcase.expectedBody {
                t.Fatalf("%s != %s", body, tcase.expectedBody)
            }
        })
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

---

If you are not returning any rich data in your errors (beyond an extra error string), then a custom error may be overkill. One can achieve the same with:

```
if errors.Is(err, NotFound) {
        return fmt.Errorf("Business Logic Error: %w", err)
}
```

`fmt.Errorf` with the `%w` wrap-verb wraps a new error with the added error message - preserving the original error if one needs to unwrap or use `errors.Is` for matching.

---

In `UserHasName` there's a fall-through bug:

```
if err != nil {
    if errors.Is(err, NotFoundError) { return /* */ }
    if errors.Is(err, DatabaseError) { return /* */ }
    
    // if err matches neither of the above checks, then the error is lost
}
```

---

Applying the above refactoring/bug-fixes: https://play.golang.org/p/N5_PAiJKzRh

Comment: Thanks for the example. I agree, that the `fmt.Errorf("Business Logic Error: %w", err)` could partially solve my problem, but as far as I understand in that case I will be forced to keep   `"Business Logic Error:"` error string in two places: `BusinessLogicError  = CustomErrorBuilder("BusinessLogicError", nil)` and  `fmt.Errorf("Business Logic Error: %w", err)`  My point was to avoid that duplication and using sentinel-style errors only

Comment: In the playground link I provided, the error string is defined only once (line 14) and reused (line 35).

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. Thank you!